# Android Studio 3.2 logcat "SHOW ONLY SELECTED APPLICATION" is not default anymore

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I have been working with Android Studio version

```
Android Studio 3.2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6
```

It has an annoying "Feature" now that every time I deploy an app onto a device I have to reselect the logcat drop down to "Show only selected application".

In fact this value only appears after the APK has been installed on the device.

In previous versions of Android Studio it "remembered" my selection.

Is there anyway I can configure Android Studio 3.2 to keep the desired setting of "Show only selected application"?

Comment: answer  from engineer responsible for the Logcat integration- see second comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9eycw8/last_call_for_flight_as_32_departing_shortly/ It will be fix in 3.3